# iCloud Drive - Keep Select Files Downloaded

Tags: macos, cloud-storage, icloud

I have a group of files (all placed in one folder) that I use daily - every few hours the files un-download themselves and I have to redownload them when needed. OneDrive has an option for forcing the files to always stay downloaded:

[image: OneDrive Options]

Is there a way to achieve this with iCloud Drive?

Comment: I am confused. The icon in the screenshot is of iCloud. Are those not iCloud quick actions?

Comment: Files being ejected suggests that your disk is not big enough to hold all the files in iCloud Drive. Having Desktop & Documents stored in iCloud Drive adds to the pressure on disk storage. How big is your Macintosh HD and how much do you have in iCloud Drive?

Comment: There is no option to keep individual files or folders "materialised".

Comment: @Ramhound The screenshot shows OneDrive icons and OneDrive actions.